# Invoke AWS SAM local function from another SAM local function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, yaml, serverless

I am trying to create an AWS SAM app with multiple AWS Serverless functions.

The app has 1 template.yaml file which have resource of 2 different serverless lambda functions, for instance "Consumer Lambda" and "Worker Lambda". Consumer gets triggered at a rate of 5 minutes. The consumer uses boto3 library to trigger the worker lambda function. This code works when the worker lambda is deployed on AWS.

But I want to test both the functions locally with Sam local invoke "Consumer" which invokes "Worker" also locally.

Here's a screenshot of the YAML file:

[image]

I am using Pycharm to run the project. There is an option to run only 1 function at a time which then creates only one folder in the build folder.

I have to test if Consumer is able to invoke worker locally in pycharm before deployment. I think there is some way to do it but not sure how to. I did some extensive search but didn't yield anything.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can start the lambda invoke endpoint in the following way (official [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-local-start-lambda.html)):

```
sam local start-lambda
```

Now you can point your AWS resource client to port 3001 and trigger the functions locally.

For eg. If you are doing this on Python, it can be acheived in the following way with boto3:

```
boto3

# Create a lambda client
lambda_client = boto3.client('lambda',
                             region_name="<localhost>",
                             endpoint_url="<http://127.0.0.1:3001>",
                             use_ssl=False,
                             verify=False)

# Invoke the function
lambda_client.invoke(FunctionName=<function_name>,
                     Payload=<lambda_payload>)
```

Comment: @umangmistrybo, if the answer did indeed address your question, do you mind accepting it. That way, others who stumble upon this can easily find the solution. Cheers.

Comment: Hi I tried this. I get the idea of having the resource running at a local point. After "sam local start-lambda" when i invoke "consumer" it is not able to invoke the "worker" from consumer. Error is Resource not found.

Comment: I would have marked it as correct but it throws an error when im trying to invoke. Not sure what is wrong

Comment: @umangMistryBO, are you invoking the first lambda function fromt he same endpoint as well? If you are doing so via PyCharm, note that it s[ins up the docker container which doesn't have access to the port 3000 from the host machine.

Comment: sam local runs on port 3001. I am invoking the first lambda function from the same endpoint. I am running the commands from terminal as per the docs.

Comment: @umangMistryBO, `sam local invoke..` doesn't invoke the lambda from the same endpoint. Do you mind updateing the question with the commands that you are using ?